# How to move category description text?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, template

How can i move the category Description text from the wrong place to the right place. See my illustration for more information.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on template path hints

> system->config->developer->Debug->template path hints

See from which template file, it gets rendered. I think it is

> catalog/category/view.phtml

Once you found the file navigate to it. Check the class for printing description.

Or you can do that using static block also.

Answer (score 1):

Category description is displayed from your theme/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml file.

In your view file you can find this code:

```
<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Copy this code from and paste it where you want to display category description.